# How to set a maximum percentage in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a calculation on my view template (slim) that will sometimes return a value over 100% -- which is good. This works:

```
- percent_complete = number_to_percentage((project.donations.total/project.goal * 100), precision: 0)
```

I'd also like a separate calculation that would cap the percentage at a maximum of 100%. So if a value is 1433%, it becomes 100%. This doesn't work and

```
- percent_graph = percent_complete unless (project.donations.total/project.goal * 100) > 100 || 100
```

Comment: `percent_graph = [percent_complete, 100].min`

Comment: I don't know if `project.donations.total` and `project.goal` are integers or floats, but you may not want integer division there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
percent_graph = [percent_complete, 100].min
```

Comment: `percent_graph = [percent_complete.to_i, 100].min` did the trick. Thanks!